# Resizing image with libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a probleme with libGDX...

I would like to resize my picture but i don't know find the ratio for this ... Can you help me ?

My code:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}


@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    float x = 0;
    this.w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    this.h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    System.out.println(w);
    System.out.println(h);
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, 1);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    imgAbalone = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/AbaloneCS5.gif"));
    imgFond = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/parquet.jpg"));
    imgAbalone.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(imgAbalone, 0, 0, 700, 700);
    spriteAbalone = new Sprite(region);
    spriteAbalone.setSize(0.9f , 0.9f);
    spriteAbalone.setOrigin(spriteAbalone.getWidth()/2, spriteAbalone.getHeight()/2);
    spriteAbalone.setPosition(-spriteAbalone.getWidth()/2, -spriteAbalone.getHeight()/2);
    TextureRegion regionFond = new TextureRegion(imgFond, 0, 0, 1000,1000);
    spriteFond = new Sprite(regionFond);
    spriteFond.setSize(1, 1);
    spriteFond.setOrigin(0,0);
    spriteFond.setPosition(-spriteFond.getWidth()/2, -spriteFond.getHeight()/2);
}
```

I don't know what to put in resize ()

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure whether this is right or not because in my own project I abstracted this code away a long time ago, but try:

```
camera.setToOrtho(false, width, height);
camera.update();
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);//if you have one
```

Answer (score 0):

do one thing, set the camera viewport like this..

```
    float scrw=320;
    float scrh=480;
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, scrw, scrh);
    camera.update();
```

here scrw is your viewport's width which you can set according to your need and scrh is your viewport's height.
using this you dont have too resize any thing..

but if you want to resize any way you can use this code

```
    float hh = (float) (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 320f);
```

then

```
    sprite.setScale(hh);
```